# How to run javascript function inside a ASPX file from a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, external-script

I have a ASPX file to process some validation from my users. I need to prepear some codes and IDs for user to work with my data. I wrote a Validation.aspx file, checking everything about my users in `Page_Load`. I want to use some javascript functions from html files.

There are some javascript functions inside ASPX file, I make them in runtime from gathering data by validation.aspx `Page_Load`.

I want to put a script inside html files like this:

```
<script src="validation.aspx?a=1234" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" ><script/>

<script> RunValidationAnswer(); <script/>
```

The `RunValidationAnswer();` function is made in runtime form user data (retriving from QueryString  [a=1234] ). I can't access `RunValidationAnswer();` in html files.

If i put the `RunValidationAnswer();` in a JS file I can access it but I lose the powerfull operations inside `Page_Load` of aspx file.

plz help me to find a way to solve my problem.

I wrote this sample script in Validation.aspx

```
<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function RunValidationAnswer()
{
alert("hi");
}
<script/>
```

It is compeletely accessible inside validation.aspx but I can't access this function from other files.

I want somthing like this inside other files:

```
<script src="validation.aspx?a=1234" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" ><script/>

<script> RunValidationAnswer(); <script/>
```

Comment: try adding runat="server" to script

Comment: runat="server" is not answer! made many new problems!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the content type of ASPX page to be javascript so the browser would know that is Javascript file, cause by default the content type of any aspx is HTML

```
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"
```

** add ; for C#

**Validation.aspx should be empty file except for this line**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ScriptTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="ScriptTest" %>
```

**And in code file, you write JS by response.write**

```
public partial class ScriptTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

        Response.Write("alert('javascript works')");
    }
}
```

**You could also just use ASPX page -without code file- like this**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ContentType="text/javascript" %>
alert("script works <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>");
```

Comment: it is my Page tag:<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ContentType="text/javascript" CodeFile="ScriptTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="ScriptTest" %>

Comment: If it is not that, then it could be javascript syntax issue.. Could you post the exact error you get.. try simple alert('') in validation.aspx to see if it works..

Comment: I write a script inside <script><script/> tag in Validation.aspx,  it is work correctly inside the validation.aspx, but I can't access the functions from other files!

Comment: OH, you need to have the ASPX file without any code execpt for first line <%@ Page ... and in code behind you write JS code without script tags and by using response.write

Comment: I wrote my Page tag above here, I have a file with just <%@Page... but not working yet

Comment: If you run validation.aspx in browser, you should only see javascript code no <script> tag.. just javascript code displayed as text file in browser